# Получить список всех видеозаписей канала на ютубе

Tags: видео, youtube, youtube-api

Здравствуйте. Кто нибудь пытался получить список всех видеозаписей канала на ютубе? Могу получить всех которые входят в плейлисты, а как получить абсолютно все?

Comment: абсолютно всех? Сгенерируйте все 11 символьные строки из набора 0-9A-Za-z_ (вроде все символы указал). Там точно будут все ссылки на видео и немного ссылок на будущие видео.

Comment: Я же уточнил (канала).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/reference?hl=ru#Video_Feeds наверное гденить в апи искать надо

Comment: я искал там, буду еще искать. У меня получается только последние 25 получить или же с плейлистов.

Comment: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=cnn&v=2&orderby=updated&alt=jsonc&q=news вот ссылка для получения всех видео CNN

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! Буду парсить :)

Comment: ссылка нерабочая